# Unable to load assembly when referencing BindingFlags type in Windows 10 Universal Windows library

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2015

When running unit tests, calling any method in my portable runtime library DLL that references the "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" generates  a FileNotFound exception, searching for "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions". The error does not occur when the same code is executed in a Windows 10 Universal app.

The project is a C# portable runtime library, configured to support .net Framework 4.6 and Windows Universal 10.0. The Test project is configured to use .net Framework 4.6.

Whenever I attempt to call a method that uses the System.Reflection.BindingFlags type, I get the following exception. The exception occurs as the call starts (presumably while jit-ing the function).

```
Test method Sfx.Test.SignalExpressionTest.TestAddExpressions threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
```

Comment: I see it, ugly bug.  Hard to diagnose, the .NETCore dependencies are impossible to untangle anymore.  The workaround is to add the Nuget package to your project.

Comment: I found this also (Unit test issue? i'm running unit test also): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/37f248bb-c45c-4b17-ae45-45913e7ce4b8/portable-class-library-fails-to-jit-when-referencing-systemreflectionbindingflags-when-running?forum=vsunittest

Comment: That is of course the exact same issue.  It is not clear to me why you don't want to add the Nuget package.  Looks like this got borken on January 15th by the commit from mellinoe which moved BindingFlags.  Just report the bug, click the New Issue button on [this web page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) to let him know.  Do keep in mind that bugs like these are pretty normal, CoreFx is moving fast and gets barely tested.  You are a pioneer with arrows in your back.

Comment: lol @pioneer with arrows in your back. COuld you explain what's going on here please. I've been in Android land for a while, and this multiplication of platforms things is new turf for me. Is that package built and maintained by core microsoft development? Is this just the New Normal, or is the cross-platform library thing just a place where anyone sensible fears to tread? (The nuget thing worked fine of course. But the concept of having to run to nuget to get core runtime libraries is unsettling, to say the least).

Comment: EHHH! must login to write a bug, such a flawed concept. I'll wait till Core is more stable...

Comment: I've encountered this same issue except the library in my case targets .NET Standard 1.4 and the caller is a full framework 4.6.1 console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding those packages is the right thing to do. Here is why you see this behavior:

1. `BindingFlags` is currently [1] exposed in `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`.
2. When you compile a .NET Core class library, the compiler records the type reference as `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions!System.Reflection.BindingFlags`.
3. When you consume the class library from a .NET Framework application, you need to add a reference to `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` otherwise the compiler cannot resolve the type. The same is true for a unit testing project which has to deploy all the code in order to run.
4. At runtime, the CLR will resolve the type, find a type forward that points to `mscorlib!System.Reflection.BindingFlags` and happily run your code.

As a general rule of thumb: .NET Core is designed to deploy the framework in an app-local fashion, in other words, when your application is deployed to a folder, the closure of all your dependencies need to be deployed too. Although unit test projects are conceptually class libraries, the same applies because they are executed like applications.

Of course, we don't expect folks to manually tweak the references and hunt down dependencies. What you currently see are pre-release bits where not all pieces in our tooling experiences do the right thing.

Two questions from my side:

1. Which unit testing framework do you use? I assume it's MSTest (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting), as opposed to xUnit or NUnit?
2. Which runner are you using? I assume it's the built-in Visual Studio Test Explorer (as opposed to ReSharper or TestDriven.NET)?

---

[1] I say currently because based on customer feedback we [decided](https://github.com/dotnet/apireviews/tree/master/2016-01-29-reflection) to move it back into `System.Reflection`, together with the APIs that take `BindingFlags`.

Comment: Yes I'm doing all my unit tests with Visual Studio unit testing, no third parties involved.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure this will work for the release of VS.

Comment: My library targets .NET Standard 1.4 and the caller is a full framework 4.6.1 console app.  No "pre-release bits" are involved but I still ran into this same issue.  It would be nice to see it actually get fixed.

Answer (score 3):

add reference to nuget packages:

```
System.Reflection
System.Reflection.Extensions
System.Reflection.Primitives
```

Comment: Add this, System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, and then it will work.